# I have Created a Flask Rest Api and configured in apache for production but is not executing db queries

Tags: python, flask

Below lines are added to httpd.conf file

```
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
    <IfModule wsgi_module>
    <Directory D:/MGM/MGMApi>
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / D:/MGM/MGMApi/wsgi_test.wsgi
    </IfModule>
```

wsgi file is created as below

```
    # test.wsgi 
    import sys 
    #Expand Python classes path with your app's path
    sys.path.insert(0, "D:\\MGM\\MGMApi")
    from wsgi import app
    #Put logging code (and imports) here ...
    #Initialize WSGI app object
    # api.add_resource(Hello, "/hello", endpoint="hello")
    application = app
```

Finally .py file to be called from above wsgi file is created as below.

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_cors import CORS
    from flask_restful import Api
    from configparser import ConfigParser
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
    from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine
    # from flask_login import LoginManager
    from flask import Flask, request
    from flask_restful import Resource
    import os

    app = Flask(__name__)
    # app.secret_key='F12Zr47j\3yX R~X@H!jmM]Lwfi?KT'
    CORS(app)
    api = Api(app)
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"config.INI"))
    app.config['WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY'] = 'random key for form'
    app.config['LDAP_PROVIDER_URL'] = 'ldap://ldap.testathon.net:389/'
    app.config['LDAP_PROTOCOL_VERSION'] = 3
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "%s://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (config.get("DB Connection", "Driver"),
                                                                  config.get("DB Connection", "Username"),
                                                                  config.get("DB Connection", "Password"),
                                                                  config.get("DB Connection", "Server"),
                                                                  config.get("DB Connection", "Database"))
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = 20
    app.secret_key = 'p9Bv<3Eid9%$i01'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)


    base_url = config.get("Run Configuration", "Base_Url")
    port = int(config.get("Run Configuration", "Port"))
    class Hello(Resource):
        def get(self):
            results = db.session.execute("select * from amount")
            print(results)
            name=request.args.get('name', '')
            return 'Hello ' + name + '!'

    api.add_resource(Hello , "/hello", endpoint="hello1")
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5080)
```

When i run in development it is running fine but when i configure using above files in production server db operations are not executed.Anyone Please help me to get out of this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I missing something or why does your wsgi.py never call `app.run()` ?

Comment: it is there at the end of .py file not in wsgi file.

Comment: I see that. But on the production server, aren't you executing the wsgi.py? Thus you never run the application.

Comment: Do we have to run it manually in production too? we are configuring it in httpd.conf file right? For sample it is working fine but when i have db operations it is not working in production.

Comment: I'm unsure, as it's been some time since I've used Apache. The servers I work with run NGINX. Each web server is then their own running service.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to host flask rest api on windows production server with apache web server?